# %matplotlib inline not working | Multiple out put is showing while using Loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Below is the screenshot i am getting, while using the for loop to create multiple Seaborn Charts,

How to avoid it, I have tried "%matplotlib" as well. its not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtkkY.png)

```
%matplotlib inline
object_columns = df_clean.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns

fig, axes = plt.subplots(14, 2, figsize=[20, 30])

for row, var in enumerate(float_columns):
    sns.boxplot(y=var, data=df_clean, ax=axes[row, 0])
    sns.histplot(y=var, data=df_clean, ax=axes[row, 1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: When I plot stuff in Jupyter notebooks, I simply write `fig;` (with a semicolon) as the last line of the cell, and it shows the plot just fine. I've never needed to use `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you! very much it worked. I really appreciate the same.